# launch DialogFragment from dialog themed Activity

Tags: android

I am trying to launch an dialog fragment from an dialog themed activity. Once the dialog fragment is launched the dialog themed activity must be exited. I use finish method after launching the dialog fragment, but it does not works that the dialog fragment is not displaying .If finish method is not used then it works, but dialog themed activity is visible behind the dialog fragment as well as I am trying to customize the Edit text view in dialog fragment by Layout `Params` but is is not reflecting in the output as you can see.One more question if you don't mind I trying to use dialog themed activity instead of context menu because customizing a context menu is big task so i used dialog themed activity with list view so that I can change background, set different icons for items in the list view.Is this a good idea or I am going against android code rule ?

[image: launch DialogFragment from dialog themed Activity]

ChooseTypeActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    clickedItem = chooseType[position];
    if (clickedItem.equalsIgnoreCase("User defined")) {
        MyDialogFragment md =
                MyDialogFragment.newInstance(android.R.drawable.alert_dark_frame,
                "Set type name :", null, CHOOSE_TYPE_ACTIVITY);
        md.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
        //finish();
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AddContactsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("chooseType", clickedItem);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

MyDialogFragment.java:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    EditText txtUserDefineValue = new EditText(getActivity());
    txtUserDefineValue.setSingleLine(true);
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 40);
    params.setMargins(5, 20, 5, 20);
    txtUserDefineValue.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```